# Different list values for dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I created a dictionary, where the key is a tuple of 3 elements and the value is a list, as so:

```
dic = {}
l = []

for z in range(0,20):
    for y in range(0,150):
        for x in range(0,200):
            for j in range(0,4):
                l.append(self.images[j].GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0))
            dic.update({(x,y,z) : l})

print(dic[(25,25,5)])
```

`images`is just a list of image data, from where I get the intensity value and store this value in list `l`.

The final result I want to see in the dictionary will have items in this form:

```
{(...),
 (150,120,10): [2,5,3,9], 
 (130,100,16): [4,1,1,8],
(...)}
```

But because the list is always being appended with elements without being reseted, I cannot obtain this result.

How can I reset the list `l` so that every tuple key has its own list value?

Comment: add `l=[]` inside the `for x...` loop, before `for j...`

Comment: try tabbing in dic.update then change l to l[-1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative way to write this, using `itertool`'s `product` function and list comprehensions:

```
from itertools import product

dic = {}
for z, y, x in product(range(20), range(150), range(200)):
    dic[x, y, z] = [self.images[j].GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0)
                     for j in range(4)]
```

Functions in `itertools` often help you avoid deep nesting, and the list comprehension allows you to create the list and assign it to the dictionary in one line (although I broke out into two for readability in this example).

Actually, since python dictionaries are unordered, assuming your `GetScalarComponentAsDouble` doesn't have any side effects, changing the loop order of `x, y z` makes the code easier to follow while producing the same output.

```
from itertools import product

dic = {}
for x, y, z in product(range(200), range(150), range(20)):
    dic[x, y, z] = [self.images[j].GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0)
                     for j in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
dic = {}

for z in range(0,20):
    for y in range(0,150):
        for x in range(0,200):
            l = []
            for j in range(0,4):
                l.append(self.images[j].GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0))
            dic.update({(x,y,z) : l})

print(dic[(25,25,5)])
```

Answer (score 3):

To make your life a bit easier, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the  [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html) module, initialized with a `list` for this case. This an a good example of their use-case:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict = defaultdict(list)  # initialize with list for values
```

This will create an empty list `[]` for each dictionary entry you create, then you can just `append` to this list *while you create the keys*. For your case, this means that in your final `for` loop you can just append the `self.image` *directly* in the dictionary:

```
for j in range(0,4):
    dict[(x, y, z)].append(self.images[j].GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0))
```

This removes the need for that `list` variable `l` all together.

---

The other way is to simply initialize a new list before the `for` loop where you actually use the list:

```
for x in range(0,200):
    l = []  # create new list
    for j in range(0,4):
        l.append(self.images[j].GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0))
    dic.update({(x,y,z) : l})
```

This will achieve the same thing **but** it will include two generally unnecessary statements.